# Run a function when a div is scrolled and also on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs when you scroll a div

```
this.$something.scroll(function () {
    // Do soemthing
});
```

How can I run a function when you scroll a div and also on page load? Ive done it with the following but there must be a cleaner way to write it?

```
this.$something.scroll(function () {
    myFunc();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    myFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the function name as the callback to the event handlers. When the event is triggered the callback function is called with the event object as parameter.

```
this.$something.scroll(myFunc);
//                     ^^^^^^

$(document).ready(myFunc);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way i know. +1.

Comment: @ebilgin, May be the shortest as well!

Comment: @Tushar, what if I want to pass some arguments in the function which is being passed as a `callback` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Then you have to use anonymous callback function and then call the function inside it. other way could be using `bind` to change the context of the function. I'll prefer anonymous function.

Comment: @Tushar, Is there any way to use `bind` without `overriding this context` as `.bind()` accepts first argument as `context`

Comment: @RayonDabre No. This is the reason I prefer to use the anonymous function